# 3x2 Figures side-by-Side

Tags: floats

following Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,
              a4paper,
              DIV=calc
            ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark,markcase=ignoreuppercase,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

% Zustandsgrößen
\newcommand{\uC}[1]{\mathrm{u_{C_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\iL}{\mathrm{i_L}}
% Eingangsgrößen
\newcommand{\Uin}{\mathrm{U_{in}}}
\newcommand{\UD}[1]{\mathrm{U_{D_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\Usboost}{\mathrm{U_{S_{boost}}}}
\newcommand{\UAC}{\mathrm{U_{AC}}}

\definecolor{tkblue}{rgb}{0,0.212,0.369}
\definecolor{tkred}{rgb}{1,0.064,0.064}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_450_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckvf}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_500_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckv}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_550_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckvv}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_600_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucks}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_650_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksv}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_700_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksi}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_750_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksiv}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_800_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucka}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_850_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckav}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_900_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckn}

\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_450_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckvfz}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_500_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckvz}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_550_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckvvz}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_600_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksz}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_650_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksvz}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_700_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksiz}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_750_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksivz}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_800_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckaz}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_850_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckavz}
\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_900_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucknz}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,ylabel=Strom in $A$]
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckvf};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckv};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckvv};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucks};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksv};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksi};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksiv};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucka};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckav};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckn};
  %\legend{$\iL_p$,$\iL_k$}  
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckvf};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckv};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckvv};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucks};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksv};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksi};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksiv};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucka};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckav};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckn};  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,ylabel=Strom in $A$]
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckvf};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckv};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckvv};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucks};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksv};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksi};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksiv};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucka};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckav};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckn};

  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckvf};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckv};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckvv};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucks};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksv};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksi};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksiv};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucka};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckav};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckn};
  %\legend{$\iL_p$,$\iL_k$}  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,
  xlabel=Duty-Cycle $\delta$,ylabel=Strom in $A$]
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckvf};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckv};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckvv};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucks};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksv};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksi};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksiv};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucka};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckav};
  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckn};
  %\legend{$\iL_p$,$\iL_k$}
  \addplot [mark=+,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckvf};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckv};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckvv};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucks};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksv};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksi};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksiv};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucka};
  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckav};
  \addplot [mark=+,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckn};  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\newpage

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,ylabel=Strom in $A$]
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckvfz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckvz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckvvz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksvz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksiz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksivz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckaz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckavz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucknz};
    %\legend{$\iL_p$,$\iL_k$}  
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckvfz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckvz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckvvz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksvz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksiz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksivz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckaz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckavz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucknz};  
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,ylabel=Strom in $A$]
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckvfz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckvz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckvvz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksvz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksiz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksivz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckaz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckavz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucknz};
  
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckvfz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckvz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckvvz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksvz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksiz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksivz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckaz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckavz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucknz};
    %\legend{$\iL_p$,$\iL_k$}  
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,
    xlabel=Duty-Cycle $\delta$,ylabel=Strom in $A$]
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckvfz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckvz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckvvz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksvz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksiz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksivz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckaz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckavz};
    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucknz};
    %\legend{$\iL_p$,$\iL_k$}
    \addplot [mark=+,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckvfz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckvz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckvvz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksvz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksiz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksivz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckaz};
    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckavz};
    \addplot [mark=+,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucknz};  
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

produces following Output:
[image: Page1]
[image: Page2]

and I would like to have something like this:

[image: Goal]

here in this *.zip the Measurementfiles are attached.

I cant upload here (i think due to safety what I can understand)
so maybe someone can help me with an example?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove (or comment out) the empty lines between the tikzpictures that you want to appear in one line.

Comment: sorry but I dont know what you mean?

Comment: `\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]` for example is separated by two empty lines. Remove them or comment them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sketch in your question, I guess you want something like the following. Since I have commented out all the `\addplot` and `\pgfplotstableread`, only the axes are shown:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,
              a4paper,
              DIV=calc
            ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark,markcase=ignoreuppercase,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

% Zustandsgrößen
\newcommand{\uC}[1]{\mathrm{u_{C_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\iL}{\mathrm{i_L}}
% Eingangsgrößen
\newcommand{\Uin}{\mathrm{U_{in}}}
\newcommand{\UD}[1]{\mathrm{U_{D_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\Usboost}{\mathrm{U_{S_{boost}}}}
\newcommand{\UAC}{\mathrm{U_{AC}}}

\definecolor{tkblue}{rgb}{0,0.212,0.369}
\definecolor{tkred}{rgb}{1,0.064,0.064}

\begin{document}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_450_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckvf}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_500_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckv}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_550_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckvv}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_600_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucks}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_650_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksv}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_700_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksi}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_750_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksiv}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_800_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucka}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_850_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckav}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_0_Uin_900_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckn}
%
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_450_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckvfz}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_500_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckvz}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_550_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckvvz}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_600_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksz}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_650_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksvz}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_700_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksiz}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_750_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucksivz}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_800_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckaz}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_850_duty_vary.dat}{\Buckavz}
%\pgfplotstableread{Buck_Uac_400_Uin_900_duty_vary.dat}{\Bucknz}



\begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,ylabel=Strom in $A$]
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckvf};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckv};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckvv};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucks};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksv};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksi};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksiv};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucka};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckav};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckn};
%  %\legend{$\iL_p$,$\iL_k$}  
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckvf};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckv};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckvv};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucks};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksv};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksi};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksiv};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucka};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckav};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckn};  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,ylabel=Strom in $A$, ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right]
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckvfz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckvz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckvvz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksvz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksiz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucksivz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckaz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Buckavz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1p}] {\Bucknz};
%    %\legend{$\iL_p$,$\iL_k$}  
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckvfz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckvz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckvvz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksvz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksiz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucksivz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckaz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Buckavz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc1k}] {\Bucknz};  
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,ylabel=Strom in $A$]
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckvf};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckv};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckvv};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucks};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksv};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksi};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksiv};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucka};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckav};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckn};
%
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckvf};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckv};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckvv};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucks};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksv};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksi};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksiv};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucka};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckav};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckn};
  %\legend{$\iL_p$,$\iL_k$}  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,ylabel=Strom in $A$, ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right]
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckvfz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckvz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckvvz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksvz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksiz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucksivz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckaz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Buckavz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLp}] {\Bucknz};
%
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckvfz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckvz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckvvz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksvz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksiz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucksivz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckaz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Buckavz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={iLk}] {\Bucknz};
    %\legend{$\iL_p$,$\iL_k$}  
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,
  xlabel=Duty-Cycle $\delta$,ylabel=Strom in $A$]
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckvf};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckv};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckvv};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucks};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksv};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksi};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksiv};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucka};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckav};
%  \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckn};
%  %\legend{$\iL_p$,$\iL_k$}
%  \addplot [mark=+,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckvf};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckv};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckvv};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucks};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksv};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksi};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksiv};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucka};
%  \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckav};
%  \addplot [mark=+,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckn};  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,
    xlabel=Duty-Cycle $\delta$,ylabel=Strom in $A$, ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right]
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckvfz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckvz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckvvz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksvz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksiz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucksivz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckaz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Buckavz};
%    \addplot [mark=x,only marks,tkred,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2p}] {\Bucknz};
%    %\legend{$\iL_p$,$\iL_k$}
%    \addplot [mark=+,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckvfz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckvz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckvvz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksvz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksiz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucksivz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckaz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,only marks,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Buckavz};
%    \addplot [mark=+,tkblue,thin] table [x={d}, y={uc2k}] {\Bucknz};  
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To add a common caption, enclose all six `tikzpicture` environments into one `figure` environment as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,
              a4paper,
              DIV=calc
            ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark,markcase=ignoreuppercase,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

% Zustandsgrößen
\newcommand{\uC}[1]{\mathrm{u_{C_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\iL}{\mathrm{i_L}}
% Eingangsgrößen
\newcommand{\Uin}{\mathrm{U_{in}}}
\newcommand{\UD}[1]{\mathrm{U_{D_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\Usboost}{\mathrm{U_{S_{boost}}}}
\newcommand{\UAC}{\mathrm{U_{AC}}}

\definecolor{tkblue}{rgb}{0,0.212,0.369}
\definecolor{tkred}{rgb}{1,0.064,0.064}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,ylabel=Strom in $A$]
%  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,ylabel=Strom in $A$, ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right]
T 
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,ylabel=Strom in $A$]
%
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,ylabel=Strom in $A$, ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right]
%
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,
  xlabel=Duty-Cycle $\delta$,ylabel=Strom in $A$]
%
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,
    xlabel=Duty-Cycle $\delta$,ylabel=Strom in $A$, ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right]  
%
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is exactly what i wanted! I havent thinked about such an easy Solution.. good to know! Thanks

Comment: is there a way to set an Caption under the last 2 Plots without destroying the alignment? I tried to use \begin{figure} but it destroys the align..

Comment: @adaptive: I have edited my answer to also address this. I hope the second MWE suits your needs.